# Pausar/parar video al cerrar modal de Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap

Estoy empezando con JQuery y se me presenta este problema.
Necesito que al reproducir el video en el modal, este se pause/pare al cerral el modal. ¿Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

```js
let modalId = $('#image-gallery');
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadGallery(true, 'a.thumbnail');

  function disableButtons(counter_max, counter_current) {
    $('#show-previous-image, #show-next-image')
      .show();
    if (counter_max === counter_current) {
      $('#show-next-image')
        .hide();
    } else if (counter_current === 1) {
      $('#show-previous-image')
        .hide();
    }
  }
  /**
   *
   * @param setIDs        Sets IDs when DOM is loaded. If using a PHP counter, set to false.
   * @param setClickAttr  Sets the attribute for the click handler.
   */
  function loadGallery(setIDs, setClickAttr) {
    let current_image,
      selector,
      counter = 0;
    $('#show-next-image, #show-previous-image')
      .click(function() {
        if ($(this)
          .attr('id') === 'show-previous-image') {
          current_image--;
        } else {
          current_image++;
        }
        selector = $('[data-image-id="' + current_image + '"]');
        updateGallery(selector);
      });

    function updateGallery(selector) {
      let $sel = selector;
      current_image = $sel.data('image-id');
      $('#image-gallery-title').text($sel.data('title'));
      if ($sel.data('image').includes('https://')) {
        $('#iframeYoutube').attr('src', $sel.data('image'));
        $('#iframeYoutube').attr('width', '100%');
        $('#iframeYoutube').attr('height', 450);
        $('#image-gallery-image').attr('src', '');
      } else {
        $('#image-gallery-image').attr('src', $sel.data('image'));
        $('#iframeYoutube').attr('src', '');
        $('#iframeYoutube').attr('width', 0);
        $('#iframeYoutube').attr('height', 0);
      }
      disableButtons(counter, $sel.data('image-id'));
    }
    if (setIDs == true) {
      $('[data-image-id]')
        .each(function() {
          counter++;
          $(this)
            .attr('data-image-id', counter);
        });
    }
    $(setClickAttr)
      .on('click', function() {
        updateGallery($(this));
      });
  }
});
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 37:
      if ((modalId.data('bs.modal') || {})._isShown && $('#show-previous-image').is(":visible")) {
        $('#show-previous-image')
          .click();
      }
      break;
    case 39:
      if ((modalId.data('bs.modal') || {})._isShown && $('#show-next-image').is(":visible")) {
        $('#show-next-image')
          .click();
      }
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col thumb">
  <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="" data-image="https://player.vimeo.com/video/315946805" data-target="#image-gallery">
    <div><img class="thumbs img-thumbnails resp"></div>
    <span class="fa fa-play size-20"></span>
    <span class="overlay dark-5"></span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="image-gallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="image-gallery-title"></h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                  </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <img id="image-gallery-image" class="img-responsive col-md-12" src="">
        <iframe id="iframeYoutube" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-left" id="show-previous-image">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                  </button>

        <button type="button" id="show-next-image" class="btn btn-secondary float-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                  </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: vas a cargar un vidoe de youtube en el modal ?

Comment: Si, pero es de vimeo

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54776959/5215609

Comment: Gracias, ya lo solucioné :)